# How to save a text file in external storage in ios using flutter?

Tags: ios, file, dart, flutter, storage

I have created an app in which user can create and save a text file in the local storage of Android. I have used **path_provider** package which gives ***getExternalStorageDirectory()*** to save the data in the external storage. But I can not find the same for **ios**. ***getExternalStorageDirectory()*** is not supported for ios.

I want to save the file so that user can later on access the file from ***Files app*** in ios.[image]

```
Future<String> get _localPath async{
var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

  return dir.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async{
  final path = await _localPath;

  return File('$path/test.txt');
}

Future<File> writeData(String msg) async{
  final file = await _localFile;

  return file.writeAsString(msg);
}
```

The above code works for Android(if storage permissions are provided). Can anyone help me for achieving the same in ios.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501445/flutter-how-to-save-a-file-on-ios/74457977#74457977

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can save the file in the NSDocumentsDirectory (`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`) and then make it available to the user.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

> Use this directory to store user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing; therefore, his directory should only contain files that you may wish to expose to the user.

To make the directory available to the user you need to open the Xcode project under 'your_app/ios/Runner.xcworkspace'. Then open the Info.plist file in the Runner directory and add two rows with the key `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`. Set the value of both keys to `YES`.

If you now open the Files app and click on 'On My iPhone' you should see a folder with the name of your application.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but the problem with this solution, is the user gets also access to all the other files, like db and json files. Is there a way to only deny access to those?

Comment: Thanks! It helped me

Comment: @nani Those should go in the library directory, not the documents directory

Comment: but when the app is uninstalll , this folder is also deleted .

Answer (score 36):

As a compliment do @ni. answer, you must enable both keys. This is what it should look on:

Xcode (info.plist):

[Info.plist on Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9xmo.png)

Editor (info.plist):

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Info in source:

> In iOS 11 and later, if both this keys **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** and the **UIFileSharingEnabled** key are YES, the local file provider grants access to all the documents in the app’s Documents directory. These documents appear in the Files app, and in a document browser. Users can open and edit these document in place.

Source: [Apple developer - iOS keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW13)

Comment: Life saver i was searching for days thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I have used below code to fix this.

```
Directory directory = Platform.isAndroid
    ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
    : await getApplicationSupportDirectory(); //FOR iOS
```

also add those files as mentioned by  @Gabrielhn

Comment: This begs the question: Does Android _not_ support getApplicationSupportDirectory()? ... https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationSupportDirectory.html implies it's avail on both platforms. Why not use app support dir for both platforms? Put another way: Why to you use ext storage dir for andriod?