# Flutter: Reading and Writing User Visible Files

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for something along the lines of `getExternalStorageDirectory` that is available in both **iOS** and **android**. The purpose of this directory is to save and retrieve .json configuration files that would be later read back by the application. However the normal `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` isn't really what I need. The user is likely to want direct access to the saved files to send them to friends, forums, etc. 
Workflows might include:

User A emails a config to User B
User uploads a configuration to a forum
User downloads a configuration from a forum
User creates a configuration offline using a json editor

It seems like I must be missing something obvious here as this seems like a common requirement but I have not found a suitable way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're speaking of the `path_provider` plugin, it actually contains a function called `getExternalStorageDirectory`, though, as the documentation states, iOS prohibits the user from arbitrarily accessing any directory on the device. I would suggest checking for the platform. If on Android, use `getExternalStorageDirectory` for Android, and if on iOS, use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` and make it visible to the user. More on that here: [How to save a text file in external storage in ios using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220612/how-to-save-a-text-file-in-external-storage-in-ios-using-flutter)

Can't think of any other way of achieving this, since iOS is very strict when it comes to file management (or anything else, really).