# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Functionality only available on Android

Tags: flutter, dart, local-storage

I am Using [path_provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) ,  with [audioplayers package](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) , I want to access getExternalStorage through the ios version, I will put my own code but this code is only available for the android version.

```
  _initial() async {
Directory? appDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
String jrecord = 'Audiorecords';

String dato = "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.wav";
Directory appDirec = Directory("${appDir!.path}/$jrecord/");
if (await appDirec.exists()) {
  filePath = "${appDirec.path}$dato";
  audioRecorder =
      FlutterAudioRecorder(filePath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.WAV);
  await audioRecorder!.initialized;
} else {
  appDirec.create(recursive: true);
  showToast(
      message: 'Start Recording , Press Start',
      stateType: StateType.warning);
  filePath = "${appDirec.path}$dato";
  audioRecorder =
      FlutterAudioRecorder(filePath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.WAV);
  await audioRecorder!.initialized;
}
```

}

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider document clearly said it . i did'nt use ios .if ios provide root folder using swift or objective c .then you can use plarform code communicate with flutter.

Comment: I know the document said it clearly, but I want another way or package that solves this issue for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220612/how-to-save-a-text-file-in-external-storage-in-ios-using-flutter